# apply CSS list style buttons to server created button controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, .net-3.5, web-parts

I have some CSS that uses lists to create 3D buttons styles similar to the link below:

```
http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5323375.html
```

My problem is I have buttons which are server controls and thus render html buttons.

The question is how would I rewrite my button code to use lists and hyperlinks so I can apply the CSS which has been already written?

All I am doing in my button code is within the onclick event setting a string value and calling a method by passing it that string value.

*I guess what I'm after is some onclick event equivalent i can hook my code into for hyperlink controls.*

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by using the LinkButton control to render the anchor tags I needed. I also used LiteralControls to render the html list elements I needed. I then added the classes as required to the created controls.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the `<asp:hyperlink` instead of the `<asp:button`?

also, in your code behind, you can add multiple CssClasses by doing something like

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("class", "style1 style2 style3")
```

Comment: thanks but i am trying to do this in codebehind or the class file as its a webpart and there is no asp page.

Comment: you can still add attributes can you not?  Sorry for not being a mind reader, are you using MVC?

Comment: i should have mentioned im doing this within a webpart in sharepoint, thanks